# How to detect a player?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I make a command block detect whether a person over a set **range** of coordinates has been killed? (without any radius, because radius is causes some major problem in the server)

Comment: I don't know much about MCPE commands, but you could try constantly teleporting an armour stand to that player, as long as the player is within 10 blocks of it or so. Once the player has moved more than 10 blocks in one tick, you can be almost sure that they died, but you would also have to consider ender pearls, portals and gateways. I don't know if the death statistic also exists in MCPE, of course you would base your detection on that if it exists.

Comment: What i'm doing is: 1. Player enters the room area 2. Clears a wall to reveal a secret compartment filled with endermites 3. Endermites kill player and 4. Kills the endermites when player dies no matter where in the room the player died.

Comment: Do (scoreboard) tags exist in PE? Then you could just tag the player when they enter the room (regular x,y,z,dx,dy,dz selector arguments) and combine that with the death scoreboard. And I repeat, I don't know much about MCPE commands, only MCJE.

Comment: Well i don't understand what dx dy and dz at all, my coordinates are 18 4 -49 to 15 4 -43

Comment: The wiki should have all the information.

Comment: It really doesn't, "The opposite corner of the value used for x" "The opposite corner of the value used for y." "The opposite corner of the value used for z." That barely explains anything

Comment: It's the other coordinates. There are also example commands there. For example `@a[x=1,y=2,z=3,dx=4,dy=5,dz=6]` selects everyone from 1 2 3 to 1+4 2+5 3+6 = 5 7 9.

Comment: If you discovered the answer to your question, would you mind adding it as an answer?

Comment: ok then........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that dx is x distance away from the command block to the y and z coordinate, (noting that d stands for distance) (after looking a bit longer I found this other site with the question and one of the responses giving a video) same with dy and dz (except the coordinates it goes to from it is different, for dy its to x and dz to x y.